Can we customize RollinFileAppender for log4Net to achieve desired naming pattern
I want to achieve a specific naming pattern for the log files generated by RollingFileAppender.
my current configuration
<appender name="LiveTouchAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\\Binayak\\log-file.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
  <datePattern value="-yyyyMMdd"
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="Header" value="&#13;&#10;--------------------- Begin Entry ---------------------&#13;&#10;" />
    <param name="Footer" value="&#13;&#10;--------------------- End Entry -----------------------&#13;&#10;" />
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%-6t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
  </layout>

current naming pattern
log-file-20240822.log  //contains newest data
log-file-20240822.1.log // contains oldest data
what i want to achieve is
log-file-20240822.log  //contains oldest data
log-file-20240822.1.log // contains newest data
